# How I can create my own code style format for Resharper 4.5?

Tags: resharper

How I can create my own code style format for Resharper 4.5?. And how i may to use it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the options in ReSharper's Code Format window allow you to specify your own style.  For instance, local private fields can be camelCased or PascalCased and can be *preceededWithAnUnderscore and appendedWithAnUnderscore*.  You can specify where your braces should be placed and you can specify where you want spaces and blank lines.

Is that what you're looking for?  Shout if not.